# App executa no emulador mas não aparece ícone

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou criando um aplicativo  para Android utilizando o Android Studio. O aplicativo funciona normalmente quando executo no emulador do android, porem, nem no emulador e nem quando gero um apk e instalo no celular o ícone não aparece, por exemplo, se eu fechar o aplicativo no emulador e quiser executar novamente tenho executar o "Run" no Android Studio para lançar o aplicativo, e quando instalo no celular instala normalmente mas após instalar não habilita a opção abrir e não aparece o ícone no menu.

Alguém sabe o que poderia ser?

Abaixo o `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="educanimais.euphoria.com.br.educanimais" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_tucano"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".splash"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".splashapp"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que a sua aplicação tenha o seu *icon* na área das aplicações terá de ter, no AndroidManifest.xml, uma Activity declarada com um `intent-filter` que, além de uma *action* `"android.intent.action.MAIN"`, tenha a *category* `"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"`.

Altere a parte da declaração da MainActivity para:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```